# Howto convert JSON to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

This is my first question to *StackOverflow*. I think answer is not so complicate, but I am very new to *Javascript*.

I have a **JQuery AJAX** function that parses this **JSON** object:

```
{
  "Users":[
    {
      "key":"1",
      "label":"Tom Clancy"
    },
    {
      "key":"12",
      "label":"Steve Martin"
    }
  ]
}
```

and should obtain the same result as:

```
var sections = [{
    key: 1,
    label: "Tom Clancy"
  }, {
    key: 12,
    label: "Steve Martin"
  }
];
```

I'm able to iterate through **JSON** element, but i don't know how to go on.

Can you provide suggestions?

EDIT: i can't still get it work...this is my code:

```
    var sections=[
        {key:1, label:"Section A"},
        {key:2, label:"Section B"},
        {key:3, label:"Section C"},
        {key:4, label:"Section D"}
    ];
    $.ajax({
    url: '/WebOffice/ListaUtenti',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) 
    {
        console.log( "success" );
        sections = data.Users;
    }});

    scheduler.createTimelineView({
        name:   "matrix",
        x_unit: "day",
        x_date: "%d %M",
        x_step: 1,
        x_size: 15,
        y_unit: sections,
        y_property: "section_id"
    });
```

The jquery ajax call doesn't assign the new value to sections (the call state is success, verified) and so scheduler still shows the original sections. Where i'm wrong?

thanks

Comment: `var sections = json_object.Users`?

Comment: To convert it to array you'd do `var arr = $.makeArray(object)`, but there's really no reason to as you can access the object just as easily.

Comment: First I would take a look at an article on associative arrays - if youre a beginner this one will sufffice - http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/ You should also post the code you have, then I/others will edit/post our answers and help you fix what you have

Comment: So simple?? I'm really very new to javascript...thank you very much!

Comment: That xkoder page is a terrible article, full of misconceptions and bad practices. I don't have time to explain the details right now, but will follow up later if anyone is interested. In the meantime:  **Not recommended.**

Comment: p.s. @NickCardoso - no offense intended by my dissing that article - you didn't write it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will explain you the process. Go to any online JSON formatter, may be [this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) one and pretty print your JSON. It will appear as.

```
{
   "Users":[
      {
         "key":"1",
         "label":"Tom Clancy"
      },
      {
         "key":"12",
         "label":"Steve Martin"
      }
   ]
}
```

So `Users` is an array of objects. `Users[0]` is first object and `Users[1]` is second object.
So you can iterate the JSON easily and obtain the result you want.

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/sbymr/

See the console for the output.

Comment: `Users[0]` is not an array...it is an object with properties `key` and `label`